# Change the end of line of a row with File.WriteAllLines();

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to write a file with this `File` class method in C#.

```
public static void WriteAllLines(string path, IEnumerable<string> contents);
```

The end of line is `CRLF` but I need this to be `LF`.

Comment: Is it because your environment has LF as a newline symbol, like Linux? Did you check Environment.Newline constant ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`WriteAllLines` uses a StreamWriter to write the lines to a file, using the newline string specified in the [NewLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

You can use the StreamWriter in your own code and use `\n` instead of `\r\n`. This has the benefit that you avoid string concatenations and generating temporary strings :

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path)) 
{
    writer.NewLine = "\n";
    foreach (var line in contents) 
    {
        writer.WriteLine(line );
    }
}
```

Using a StreamWriter directly allows you to use asynchronous methods as well:

```
public async Task MyMethod()
{
    ....
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path)) 
    {
        writer.NewLine = "\n";
        foreach (var line in contents) 
        {
            await writer.WriteLineAsync(line);
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

This can be a big benefit when writing large files, in server and web applications and web sites where you want to keep blocking at a minimum

Answer (score 2):

There are so many ways of writing to a file, I'd just go with a different one - only a couple lines:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path)) {
    foreach (var line in contents) {
        writer.Write(line + "\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `WriteAllLines()`, you can join the strings yourself and use `WriteAllText()`:

```
File.WriteAllText(string path, string.Join("\n", contents) + "\n");
```

Comment: This generates a huge string in memory, so I'd avoid this unless you guarantee that your file will be small. Plus, you want `\n`, not `\r`.

Comment: @JoeEnos Fixed, thanks. Also, it's text, so I highly doubt it's that huge.

Comment: @itsme86 imagine a log file. Or a web server. Doubling the memory usage can cause a lot of harm when you have even moderate traffic. Or consider the other side: By joining you end up buying a larger cloud VM to serve the same traffic

Answer (score 0):

```
            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < 99999; i++)
            {
                builder.Append(i.ToString() + '\n');
            }

            File.WriteAllText("asd.txt", builder.ToString());
```

That is obviously with boilerplate code. Keep in mind that using a `StringBuilder` instead of a `string[]` is also faster.

[image]

Comment: Why create the string in memory when you can write it out immediately?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with this, it avoids re-writing to memory and works quickly.  This assumes you are only using ASCII and don't need to overwrite the file - otherwise use a different encoding and change the file mode accordingly.

```
    public static void WriteAllLines(string path, IEnumerable<string> contents)
    {
        using (var s = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append))
        {
            foreach (var line in contents)
            {
                var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{line}\r");
                s.Write(bytes,0,bytes.Length);
            }
            s.Flush();
            s.Close();
        }
    }
```